# How do I implement actor based concurrency in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I need to use actions and actors for CRUD logic in my application. I am following an architecture document that defines an `action` as being the synchronous part and the `actor` as being the asynchronous part, which makes sense. However, the actor, which writes data back to a file, only needs to do its own operations if an action has completed successfully. For example, if an entry is successfully updated, then write the data back. If the entry was not successfully updated, then don't write the data back. I was thinking of calling `action.execute` in an `execute()` function in an actor:

```
public void execute() {
    if(action.execute()) {
        executeAsynchronously();
    }
}
```

However, this seems like it doesn't really fit in with the actor model. As more background I have a manager class that manages all the entries and data. There are `add()`, `delete()`, and `update()` methods in that class that each do:

```
public void addEntry(UserkEntry entryModel, boolean notify) {
    assert entryModel != null;
    synchronized (this) {
        AddEntryAction action = new AddEntryAction();
        UserDirectoryActor actor = new UserDirectoryActor(action);
        addActor(actor);
        actor.execute();
    }
}
```

And my method to add an actor:

```
protected final synchronized void addActor(UserDirectoryActor actor) throws BusinessException {
    for(UserDirectoryActor act : actors) {
        if(act.equals(actor)) {
            UserServiceFw.log.error("Actor for " + act.getAction() + " already exists");
            throw new BusinessException("UserDirectoryActor could not be added for: " + act.getAction());
        }
    }
    actors.add(actor);
}
```

How can I modify my code to better fit the actor model? And is the synchronization overkill?

Comment: Did you take a look in SO Docs ? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/121/concurrent-programming-threads

Comment: @MickaëlB I didn't see anything in there on actors

Comment: Can you try to elaborate upon why you don't think your current setup doesn't fit the actor model as you say ?

Comment: In my opinion, it seems like it is bad practice to call the synchronous part from the actor because then actor is somewhat responsible for synchronous operations. I've seen other examples where the action is executed outside of the actor, but in that case the action is what executed the actor, which doesn't make sense eitehr

Comment: If you're currently questionning the actor model in concurrent programming you might have chosen the wrong model.

Comment: I'm just questioning my implementation of it